# ZABBIX 3.0.10 - Get incoming/outgoing traffic with ZABBIX API

Tags: php, api, zabbix, network-traffic, network-monitoring

I want to know if through the `ZABBIX API` is something method or parameter for obtain the network traffic (i.e., kbps/mbps...).

I searched for it in the official page and not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Zabbix API, [history.get](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/api/reference/history/get) method.